# Is $\mathrm{Top}$ a coexact category?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, compactness

The question in the title reduces to:

Is it true that [equivalence relations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+relation) are [effective](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/congruence) in $Top^{op}$?

Here is some information in this direction:

The category $Top^{op}$ is regular, and therefore $Top^{op}$ is [Barr exact](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+category) if and only if equivalence relations are effective.

Note also the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is coexact (see [Borceux](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=5i2v9q0m5XAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Borceux&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi88KLnxKTVAhXEYVAKHRu4Co0Q6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=coexact&f=false))

Comment: This paper claims that it is not the case : http://www.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1995__36_1_3_0.pdf. No reason is given, but note that for a quasivariety, being exact is equivalent to being closed under regular images in the variety; so if you can find an example of a surjective grid homomorphism $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ satisfies the Horn clause but $Y$ doesn't , it would prove that $Top$ is not coexact.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that is all I really needed to know and answers my question. Although it would be nice to have a counter-example readily available.